# Index Out of Bounds error during interatction

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am running a menu that a user can choose from a list of options they can choose from. One of the options is a user can add a string to a specific index using Array List. This is being processed throug a method called Public Void Set Element(); when I run the program and choose this option by adding a string and an index I get a Index Out of Bounds error. Here is my code any suggestiolns

```
public void setElement(int setIndex, Object element)
{
    if (setIndex < 0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    ListIterator li = listIterator();
    while (li.hasNext()) {
         li.next();
        if (setIndex == 0) {
            li.set(element);
            return;
        }
        setIndex--;
    }
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

Comment: why aren't you using [`List.set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,E))?

Comment: 1. Identify why your getting the error....Either your setIndex < 0 or your went through the whole array without setIndex == 0. 2. Debug the program! Either put some breakpoints in or print out some variables and deterime why #1 is happening... Its the debugging process.

Comment: It seems to me that, if your code is throwing the exception, you should know why.  Have you done any debugging at all?

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is an arraylist, why not just use ArrayList.set(int index, E element)?

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the probable reason's why your code is not working:

- How do you know that the index you re giving it isn't indeed out of the list's bounds?
- Did you initialize your list prior to calling this method?
- Is `listIterator()` returning the correct iterator

Your best bet would be as ns47731 says to insert print statements to check the value of the index and the length of the list.